# python ImportError: cannot import name libsvm

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, libsvm, scikit-learn

I trying to use `svm` through `scikit-learnkit` for python. But I am continually getting following errors.

```
> from sklearn import svm 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/__init__.py", line 13, in 
<module>
    from .classes import SVC, NuSVC, SVR, NuSVR, OneClassSVM, LinearSVC 
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/classes.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base import BaseLibLinear, BaseSVC, BaseLibSVM 
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import libsvm, liblinear 
ImportError: cannot import name libsvm
```

I have checked `/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/libsvm.so` is present

Comment: I am pretty new to python. I don't know, exact working of python import statement. But i think , import can't load .so file directly. there should be other way around. please help me out with this

Comment: How did you install scikit-learn?